# EXCEL: if a cell in column_A contains word from column_C, then insert the word next to it (from column_D) INTO B

Tags: excel

excel:
if A1 = a word from column_C (a long list),
then insert the next word from column_D (a second long list) into B.

```
     A       B         C         D
1   apple            banana      yellow
2   banana           apple       healthy
3   ...              chocolate   tasty
4   ...              ...         ...
5   ...              ...         ...
```

**results:**

```
     A       B        *C       D*
1         healthy
2         yellow
```

...

Comment: Simple VLOOKUP or XLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: i tried xlookup: #NAME?

Comment: Only available in later versions of Excel. Use VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in the B1 cell and move the formula down:

```
=INDEX(C:D, MATCH(A1,C:C,0),2)
```

Hope it helps (:

[image]